# Beforeremote for all api calls loopback

Tags: node.js, rest, hook, loopbackjs

Is it possible to write a common beforeRemote hook for all api calls in loopback. Currently I am able to write beforeRemote hook for all api's in a particular model through that models object like:

```
modelObj.beforeRemote('*', function (ctx, req, next) {
    //code
    next()
});
```

Likewise is it possible to write one before remote for all api calls. Any help would be appreciated! Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer and I am posting it here so that someone could use this in the same situation. 
In a boot script file, use the following code:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var remotes = app.remotes();
  remotes.before('**', function (ctx, next) {
    //Code to execute before all api calls goes here
    next();
  });
};
```

Thats it!!!!